# SQL Server 2017 Developer edition user cannot connect

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2017

I have SQL Server 2017 Developer edition. I am creating user there with server authentication:

[image]

After adding, I can see user in logins for the server:

[image]

but when I am trying to connect with this user, I get an error:

[image]

stus and grants to connect are in place:

[image]

I restart server after adding  user still not able to login. Is it some of the limitations for Developer edition?

Comment: check the user status if user has access to login. This error usually shows up if you are entering wrong password as well. Why not set a new password and try again.

Comment: @TheIntegrator it  is  there , just don't understand what is going on with it

Comment: @TheIntegrator password set as 1234, because it is test enviroment

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a "Community" edition (Visual Studio does) - but there's a free-to-use **Express** edition - is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @marc_s I was talking about  Developer edition (which is same as Community  for VS)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on your server properties, select security, and then set the authentication to mix mode. "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you It was set as Win authentication mode only, after switching and restarting it start working  properly

Comment: This solved the issue for me, however i had to restart SQL Server before i could finally login using SQL authentication.

Just for the record, closing and reopening SQL Management Studio does not restart SQL Server. You must go to services and stop and the restart SQL Server or just reboot your machine so that the change can take effect.