# Why use Visual Studio 2013 + Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer to connect Database have blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I use Visual Studio 2013 + Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer to connect Database have blank page.

I use guide at [[SQL Server 2017 Developer edition user cannot connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916013/sql-server-2017-developer-edition-user-cannot-connect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916013/sql-server-2017-developer-edition-user-cannot-connect) cannot to solve problem , I have to true solve answer to connect Database not to blank page.

**Image to describe in present.**

1. I have settings to mix authentication mode.

   [image]
2. I have settings to open sa user completely.

   [image]
3. I use localhost:8081 and open Welcome Screen normally.

   [image]
4. I set password of user sa to blank.

   [image]
5. I try compile to code in example and have blank page (no table process).

   [image]

**My Code.**

**SQL**

```
USE [mydatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[customer]    Script Date: 05/01/2012 16:44:29             ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customer](
[CustomerID] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CountryCode] [varchar](2) NULL,
[Budget] [float] NULL,
[Used] [float] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('C001', 'Win Weerachai', 'win.weerachai@a.com', 'TH', 1000000, 600000);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('C002', 'John  Smith', 'john.smith@a.com', 'EN', 2000000, 800000);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('C003', 'Jame Born', 'jame.born@a.com', 'US', 3000000, 600000);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('C004', 'Chalee Angel', 'chalee.angel@a.com', 'US', 4000000, 100000);
```

**ASP.Net C#**

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<script runat="server">

SqlConnection objConn;
SqlCommand objCmd;

void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    String strConnString;
    strConnString = "Server=localhost:8081;UID=sa;PASSWORD=;database=mydatabase;Max Pool Size=400;Connect Timeout=600;";
    objConn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    objConn.Open();

    BindData();
}

void BindData()
{
    String strSQL;
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer";

    SqlDataReader dtReader;
    objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn);
    dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

    //*** BindData to Repeater ***//
    myRepeater.DataSource = dtReader;
    myRepeater.DataBind();

    dtReader.Close();
    dtReader = null;

}

void Page_UnLoad()
{
    objConn.Close();
    objConn = null;
}

</script>
<html>
<head>
<title>a.com ASP.NET - SQL Server 2012</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>CustomerID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>CountryCode</th>
            <th>Budget</th>
            <th>Used</th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><asp:Label id="lblCustomerID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustomerID") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:Label id="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td align="center"><asp:Label id="lblCountryCode" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CountryCode") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td align="right"><asp:Label id="lblBudget" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Budget") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td align="right"><asp:Label id="lblUsed" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Used") %>'></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>           
</ItemTemplate>
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
        <td align="center"><asp:Label id="lblCustomerID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustomerID") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:Label id="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td align="center"><asp:Label id="lblCountryCode" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CountryCode") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td align="right"><asp:Label id="lblBudget" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Budget") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td align="right"><asp:Label id="lblUsed" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Used") %>'></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>           
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, could you try to put some test message before `<form id="form1" runat="server">` ? to see if it actually renders the html or just fetch nothing from the database.. though by the look of it, seems it even does not render the title for the html page.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa : I try some test message before `<form id="form1" runat="server">` not render the title for the html page same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you very much to suggestion.

I found answer to solve problem = During saving code file , set charset UTF-8 to fix problem.